# ajax call with jquery and json return error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, status

Here is my problem :

i try to do an ajax request with JQuery,
if i do it without using "json" i have no error... but using json in my case is useful because i have to retrieve 3 different data... so an array IS the solution...
when i execute the code i have readyState 4, error 500, ... i guess it is a syntax error... but i can't find it...

here is the code from the php file my ajax calls :

```
if($country == 23){
    $doIt = $db->prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $doIt->execute();
    $queryCom = "SELECT * FROM division WHERE division_country = $pays ORDER BY division_name";
    $mysql = $db->prepare($queryCom);
    $mysql->execute();
    $division='Division : <select required name="divisionD" id="divisionD">';
    foreach($mysql as $data){
        $division.='<option value="'.$data["division_id"].'">'.$data["division_name"].'</option>';
    }
    $division.='</select>';
    $town = '<option value=''>select division first...</option>';
    $cp = "<option value=''>select division first</option>";
    $res = array(
        'division'=>$division,
        'town'=>$town,
        'cp'=>$cp
    );
    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: What version of php are you running? `json_encode` was introduced in PHP 5.2 so if you have an earlier version this could cause the error

Comment: well, the problem is not the version of php... i noticed that for some values its ok, for some others it is not... i think that it is related to the special chars contained in my db... idk why... still searching...

Comment: Just spotted the issue, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line you are separating the string accidently.

```
$town = '<option value=''>select division first...</option>';
                       ^^--- here is your issue
```

This should be

```
$town = '<option value="">select division first...</option>';
```

Comment: O...M...G... how could i miss that? oO
Thankss! :D

Comment: just opened a new thread with another question if you wanna help :P
JSON objects are really sensitive to case, characters,... sometimes its really hard to find where the problem is with json... thanks!